# toggle button pressed color

Tags: html, css, gwt

i am using toggle buttons in my application, i would like to set the backgound-color when the button is pressed.

how can i know what is the proper attribute?

and in general is there any place that i can know which CSS attribute has which effect on the HTML element?

Comment: how do you plan on changing the color? javascript? jquery? backend of some sort? if you just want the css attribute, it's `background-color`

Comment: From his tags, it looks like he's using [gwt] Google Web Toolkit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using GWT ToggleButton, then you may

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ToggleButton;
final ToggleButton tb = new ToggleButton( "my button text" );
if (tb.isDown()) {
   tb.addStyleName("pressed"); // or tb.setStyleName("pressed");
}
```

and in your css file:

```
.pressed { background-color: blue;  } /* any color you want */
```

Another way - to change just background of this given button:

```
tb.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("background", "green");
```

Answer (score 0):

I know GWT is similar to jQuery, but I've never used it... with jQuery I'd do this (I wasn't sure what kind of button tag you were using, so I included both):

CSS

```
input, button {
 background-color: #555;
 color: #ddd;
}
.clicked {
 background-color: #f80;
}
```

HTML

```
<button type="button">Click Me</button>
<input type="button" value="Click Me" />
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('button, :button')
  .mousedown(function(){ $(this).addClass('clicked') })
  .mouseup(function(){ $(this).removeClass('clicked') })
  .mouseout(function(){ $(this).removeClass('clicked') });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> and in general is there any place that i can know which css atribute has which effect on the HTML element?

Yes, http://www.w3schools.com/css/ has most of what you will probably need. Check the left column for the CSS-property you're looking for.

Regarding your first question, I you can just use the *btn:active, btn:hover, btn:visited* properties. (i.e. your button has the class/id 'btn'.)

Good luck